# Mysql insert into query function with if if condition

Tags: mysql

[image]

[image]

I have a problem with Mysql. I tried several things but I can't find a solution.

I have 2 tables (seen in the first screenshot - `user` and `completed`) and will create a new one in the following format (as shown in screenshot 2).

I tried it with `INSERT INTO`, but the result is not so good (see screenshot 2).

Can anyone help with this?

To fill `User`:

```
INSERT INTO temptest (Name, ID)
    SELECT user.email, user.id
    FROM user
```

To fill `course 1`:

```
INSERT INTO temptest (Kurs1)
    SELECT course_completions.timecompleted
    FROM user, course_completions, temptest
    WHERE user.id = course_completions.userid
      AND user.email = temptest.Name
      AND course_completions.course = 19
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

**If works like this:**

```
IF(<condition>, <value if true>, <value if false>)

example- 
SELECT book_name,
IF(pub_lang='English',"English Book","Other Language") 
AS Language 
FROM book_mast;
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:

```
UPDATE temptest, user, course_completions
SET temptest.Kurs2=ifnull(course_completions.timecompleted,'0')
where user.id = course_completions.userid
and user.id = temptest.id
and course_completions.course = 3
```